# override OnActionExecuting for testing request does user authorised for call action or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to override controller OnActionExecuting method, and i will check action and controller user has right or not.

```
    public class BrowseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //TODO: ask service user has right this action.
            //string actName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            //string cntName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
            //foo(actName, cntName, userInfo) if return false go NoAccess page!
            //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("_NoAccessRight");

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
     }
   }
```

I suppose that after user right validation

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("_NoAccessRight");
```

But I could not get page "_NoAccessRight" and also ~/shared/_NoAccessRight"

Could you please give idea? Thanks.

Comment: You're not redirecting to an `Action` but a file. The simplest method would be to create an action that returns `return View("_NoAccessRight")` instead.

Comment: @BuildStarted  its nice idea, but i am far machine now... i will try few hours later. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To help you for later

```
public class BrowseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToAction("NoAccessRight");
   }

   public ActionResult NoAccessRight() 
   {
       return View("_NoAccessRight");
   }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work... may be I should write code OnActionExecuted? But when I override OnExecuting I thought that stop operation before executing.

Comment: Omit "new" from RedirectToAction("NoAccessRight") (at least in MVC3).